# loop through html table and check if a checkbox is checked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

What I'm trying to do here is validating HTML table. I need at least one checkbox to be checked before proceeding. It's doing what it's need to do, except when I don't check a checkbox.

It loops the alert "nothing found" by the count of data on the HTML table. How can I make it better? I need to loop inside the table to get the data on the same row with the checkbox checked.

**JS**

```
$('#dataTable').find('tr').each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') ) {
        alert "found"
        //im getting data here.
        });
    }else{
        alert "NOthing found"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to loop through anything.  Just look for a checked checkbox inside dataTable with your selector.  If it exists, then your "true" condition is met.

```
if ($('#dataTable input[type="checkbox"]:checked').size()) {
    // Proceed
}
```

Now, if you want to do something with the data inside the "checked" rows, you could do something like this:

```
var checkedItems = $('#dataTable input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    // Do something with the row
    console.log($(this).parent('tr').find('.data-selector').val());
});
if (!checkedItems.size()) {
    // Nothing was checked
}
```

Comment: This will always be true

Comment: `$(...)` returns an object which never will evaluate to false. You have to check the `.length` property

Comment: This hardly answers the question as he clearly states he needs to loop through the acceptable tr's to do something and not just check if something is checked. Still, not a bad piece of code~

Comment: @Steven Moseley 'I need to loop inside the table to get the data on the same row with the checkbox checked.' as quoted above. Quite clearly too

Comment: @Elentriel - Good point, I guess I misread that.  Added an example of how to manipulate data for reach row using the same methodology.

Comment: @Steven Moseley yup, this is the stuff. removed my downvote and upvoted~

Comment: thanks it's working. but how can i retrieve the data which checkbox is checked on the html table?

Comment: @knowmeifyou - You need to provide more info on what data you want, exactly.  Your original post is missing the full html and explanation of what data you want to extract.

Answer (score 3):

In stead of alerting throughout the loop, why not use a flag and update it when something is found. Based on the flag, (at the end  - after the loop) just display the status!.
 I hope the following will modification will help you:

```
var found = false;
$('#dataTable').find('tr').each(function () {   
var row = $(this);
if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') ) {
    found=true;
    //alert ("found"); 
    // Do your job here
    }
else{
     //alert "NOthing found"
     //found=false;
    };
});
if (!found){
    alert("Nothing Found");
}
else{
     alert("Found");// Or you can omit the else part
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Likeso you will execute your code for every checked row, and if no row is checked, you will get to execute what you decide is apropriate, without much resources going to waste

```
  var is_table_empty = true;
 jQuery('#dataTable').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
    var row = jQuery(this).closest("tr");
    //do what needs to be done to an active row
    is_table_empty= false;
  });
  if(is_table_empty)
  {
     //do what you need to do if nothing is clicked
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this same as your code.

```
var checkFound = false;

$('#dataTable').find('tr').each(function() {
  var row = ;
  if (!checkFound && $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
    checkFound = true;
    return false;
  }
});

if (checkFound)
  alert('checked Found');
else
  alert('nothig checked');
```

Comment: if cost. Selectors cost. Still, as far as correct answers go, this is one